# Next.js and Semantic UI, Tab Element, Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, next.js

I am trying to implement [tabs from semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab) into my Next.js app.

I am getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>   Check the render method of `TabExampleBasic`.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleBasic = () => (
  <Tab panes={panes} />
)

export default TabExampleBasic
```

I imported this component into pages/index.js. Other components from semantic-ui like Card, Grid or Accordion do work without a hassle.

I am working with this example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-semantic-ui

Comment: Is the 'semantic-ui-react' installed properly? Try to `console.log(Tab);` after import. If it shows undefined here is the issue.

Comment: You are right, there is the issue. I reinstalled it and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tab` component was added in `0.70.0`, check that you running this version or higher.